# Can someone compare and contrast Linux "ln -s" and Windows "mklink /J"

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, symbolic-link

I am very familiar with command line commands in linux, and how symlinks(ln -s) work. I am trying to duplicate this feature in windows. Specifically I would like to convert my downloads folder that is on my SSD hard drive to be on my h drive. Drives as follows

```
C:\User\Users\Downloads

H:\User\Users\Downloads
```

If I were to do this in linux I would just do the following

```
$sudo mv C:\Users\User\Downloads H:\Users\User\Downloads
$sudo ln -s H:\users\User\Downloads C:\Users\User\Downloads
```

In windows I did the following

Running CMD as Admin

```
C:\Users\User>move C:\Users\User\Downloads H:\Users\User\Downloads
C:\Users\User>mklink /J C:\Users\User\Downloads H:\Users\User\Downloads
```

Have I duplicated the functionality I expect? When I try and do this with other folders after move I get a permission denied error. Probably a program running accessing that folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can't move downloads folder directly, beacuse it iself is moreless a symbolic link. If you open the properties of it, you will be able to move it from there.

Comment: The Downloads *library* is a reference, but the folder that is referenced is very much real. Symlinking the folder would work, but the preferred solution (as the answer states) is to use the Properties window to move the library.